# Define JSON Data Attributes to use in Tooltip (Tooltip Shows "Undefined")

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have looked at the other SO questions related to this issue, implemented the solutions, and have yet to have success.

I have a d3 force directed diagram driven by an external JSON file that has five attributes: source, target, source_title, target_title, and value.

Sample of JSON:

```
[{"source":"Michael Scott", "source_title":"boss", "target":"Jim Halpert", "target_title":"salesman", "value":"1"},
{"source":"Pam Beasley", "source_title":"receptionist", "target":"Jim Halpert", "target_title":"salesman", "value":"1"},
{"source":"Pam Beasley", "source_title":"receptionist", "target":"Angela", "target_title":"accountant", "value":"1"}]
```

Current Script:

```
<script>

d3.json("IA_Data.json", function(error, data){

data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.source_title = d.source_title;
    });

var links = data;

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 2000,
    height = 1000;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(5)
    .charge(-400)
    .gravity(.2)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var tip = d3.tip()
          .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
          .offset([-10, 0])
          .html(function(d) {return d.source_title;});
svg.call(tip);

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

});

</script>
```

As you can see, I am trying to return `value` in the .html line of d3.tip. My latest attempt at initializing `value` is in this section:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.source_title = +d.source_title;
    });
```

This resulting tooltips show "undefined", implying the `source_title` is not defined properly. If I swap `source_title` for `name` in d3.tip, the `source`/`target` text shows in the tooltip. How should I define the 'source_title' attribute properly?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Hi can you share a part of your json file?

Comment: Why do you just have a closing span?

Comment: I updated the post to include an expanded sample of my json file. In addition, I changed `value` to `source_title` (realizing value doesn't really make sense for two nodes), and the problem is still there.

Comment: The span tag is from an example of tooltips...it doesn't actually do anything though, and it is now taken out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `source_title` in your nodes array.

The solution is simple: create that key/value pair when you populate the nodes array:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
        name: link.source,
        source_title: link.source_title//creating 'source_title' here
    });
});
```

Here is a demo with your code (note: only two circles have title here):

```js
var data = [{
  "source": "Michael Scott",
  "source_title": "boss",
  "target": "Jim Halpert",
  "target_title": "salesman",
  "value": "1"
}, {
  "source": "Pam Beasley",
  "source_title": "receptionist",
  "target": "Jim Halpert",
  "target_title": "salesman",
  "value": "1"
}, {
  "source": "Pam Beasley",
  "source_title": "receptionist",
  "target": "Angela",
  "target_title": "accountant",
  "value": "1"
}];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.source_title = d.source_title;
});

var links = data;

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
    name: link.source,
    source_title: link.source_title
  });
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
    name: link.target,
    target_title: link.target_title
  });
});

var width = 300,
  height = 150;

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
  .links(links)
  .size([width, height])
  .linkDistance(5)
  .charge(-400)
  .gravity(.2)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("ceciliaPayne")
  .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "link " + d.type;
  })
  .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
    return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
  });

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.source_title;
  });
svg.call(tip);

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 6)
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So this solution worked for all of the fields I added initially. I just added another one and it didn't work. Any idea off the top of your head why that would be?

Comment: That code doesn't use a traditional array for links and nodes. It populates the nodes array using the links and, doing so, it changes the links array.

Comment: That makes sense - but how would that affect adding new elements to the nodes? The links already include the elements, so it should just be telling the nodes that those elements belong to them. Essentially, shouldn't it be possible to populate the nodes with an unlimited number of key value pairs?

Comment: No, it's not possible using this method here, only if you create the nodes and links array individually, and with a precise match.

Comment: It worked for the first 8 or 9 attributes though, that's what's confusing me. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Would it be possible to add an example of this other method?

Comment: Please, post another question regarding this issue.

Comment: Sure! Thank you again for the help.